# Force php through the .net engine in iis7

Tags: .net, php, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I have converted a php to asp.net mvc and have it hosted with the Rackspace cloud. All works great apart from some php links are still linked from other sites and within search engines. My question is what do I need to add to my web.config to force php sites to go through the .net engine?

These links work as expected as I can catch the 404 and redirect where need be:-

http://www.securahome.net/myjunk.info

http://www.securahome.net/myjunk.phpp

However this one doesn't:-

http://www.securahome.net/myjunk.php

> I have spoken to Rackspace cloud and
>   they say "its not possible as IIS
>   doesn't recognize php files. You can
>   setup mime types to handle them"

This however makes no sense and I think they did not understand the problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Probably this is because rackspace cloud sites reroutes php files to its linux cluster to handle them. IIS7 should be able to map them to .net, just like apache can map .aspx to php...

Comment: I agree they have misunderstood your problem - they think you want to host PHP code in IIS, whereas what you actually want is (presumably) to set up some rewrite rules to change .php to .aspx or whatever.

In Apache I'd use mod_rewrite for this, not idea what IIS equivalent is (quick SO search turns up this: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour with the Rackspace Cloud support team we finally got an answer. They allowed me to use a .htaccess file so I could do a site wide redirect on an php file. Not ideal but it got somewhere where I needed to get to.

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IIS url rewriting module for this:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: No the problem is that it seems that PHP is getting hit before IIS, so even a rewrite will not work. I cant use .htaccess either.